# Selecting the right CssSelector or TagName

Tags: c#, selenium

Basic Information
I have this software that I am developing for my personal use because im using it as a way to learn Selenium (By trial and error and so far I know the basics because I already went through it)

What the software does
It will analyze the top 5 most active stocks from a list on the website and print it out on to the software (Pretty simple right?)

The Issue

At this moment I've made it so it pulls a name & the percentage of top item from the list on this website (which used to be the top one) but then it changed to the 3rd one and what it does when I actually press the button is (as I just explained) it pulls the third option which is the one that used to be the first one

What I WOULD like it to do

I would need the correct TagName or the CssSelector which shows whats in the list from 1-5 EVEN if it changes, I would like it to change when the website changes

Example

I press the button (label11_Click) (Sorry for the bad naming on my part)
It shows the top 5 items
I close the app and wait 24 hours
The list changes on the website
I reopen the application after 24 hours
I press the same button (label11_Click)
it shows the new top 5 items

```
private void label11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var getTopFive = new FirefoxDriver();
    getTopFive.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tradingview.com/");

    IList<IWebElement> movies = getTopFive.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[data-symbol='NASDAQ:SIRI']")); 


    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
        activeTextBox.Text = movies[i].Text;

    }

}

private void activePan_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Label scan = new Label();
    scan.Text = "Test";
}

private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var homePage = new FirefoxDriver();
    homePage.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.vargadevelopments.com");
}

private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

}
```

}

List: https://embed.gyazo.com/75b4901627b3b7fc1736cc3d333a1995.png
https://embed.gyazo.com/60e4766238cc6668805b4c53947dfff7.png

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Is it that you're having trouble selecting the element in the table that contains the `data-symbol` data attribute?

Comment: What I dont understand is
IList<IWebElement> movies = getTopFive.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody tr"));

To be more specific
FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody tr"));

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to select the table then get each the symbol name in the table. You can do this using `By.XPath` and `getAttribute`. Something like below:

```
//Select the table rows that have the symbol names
var tableRows = getTopFive.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class='three-colomns-colomn active-quotes quote-tabbed-widget']//table/tbody/tr[@class='quote-ticker-inited']"));

//Loop through each row returned and get the full symbol name
foreach(var tableRow in tableRows )
{
    //Get the full symbol name (eg. NASDAQ:ABC)
    string fullSymbol = tableRow.getAttribute("data-symbol");

    //Separate the market and symbol name
    string market = fullSymbol.Substring(0,fullSymbol.indexof(":") - 1);
    string symbol = fullSymbol.Substring(fullSymbol.indexof(":") + 1);
}
```

A quick run-down of what the XPath is selecting:

- `//div[@class='three-colomns-colomn active-quotes quote-tabbed-widget']` selects the container of the most active table
- `//table` selects the table element that is an indirect child of the container
- `/tbody` selects the table body that is a direct child of the table
- `/tr[@class='quote-ticker-inited']` selects the table rows with the right class that are a direct child of the table body

If you aren't familiar with XPath see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) and [here](http://cheryjose.blogspot.ca/2013/03/using-xpath-in-identifying-web-objects.html)

I haven't tested the C# code but I did test the XPath query in Chrome and it selected the correct 5 table rows.